# PowerShell File rename

Tags: windows, powershell, rename, file-rename, powershell-4.0

How to ignore **file rename** if the filename already contains string during file rename process.

My example:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.csv", "TC.csv" }
```

I would like to rename just files without string "TC" in filename - for example:

`abc.csv` to rename
`defTC.csv` do not want to rename

Comment: `Get-ChildItem|Where-Object{$_.Basename -notlike "*TC"}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could filter off the files which don't require the rename with a regex:

```
?{!($_.fullname -match "TC\.csv")}
```

So, for your example:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" | 
?{!($_.fullname -match "TC\.csv")} |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.csv", "TC.csv" }
```

Incorporate a date filter into this as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" | 
?{!($_.fullname -match "TC\.csv") -and $_.CreationTime -ge (get-date).AddDays(-1).Date} |
Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "\.csv", "TC.csv" }
```

Comment: @Mathias - Thanks, fixed.

Comment: How to prepare condition to copy just files with current and one day before current day in filename?  My current code is: Copy-Item -Path "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" -Destination \\Oracle\MP

Comment: It could also be condition for current file creation day and one creation day before. My files look like: abc27.11.2014TC.csv for example.

Comment: I've incorporated a date filter into the answer for the current question, the logic would be the same for a file copy.  You could ask another question specifically for how to do this for a file copy but I suspect it would be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

As a simpler and more straightforward solution you could just filter into a ForEach loop and use an IF statement. Probably not quite as efficient but easier to maintain and adapt for other uses.

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" | Foreach-Object { 
    if ($_.Name -notlike "*TC*") { 
        Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -Replace "\.csv", "TC.csv") 
    } 
}
```

Alternatively pass it to a Where filter and then to the rename (note this particular syntax requires PS v3):

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\Shares\WinCAP Data\DAYPROT\OFS-222_2\*.csv" | Where Name -notlike "*TC*" | Rename-Item $_ ($_.Name -Replace "\.csv", "TC.csv")
```