# How to prevent PowerShell -Recurse from renaming first file twice?

Tags: powershell, recursion, batch-rename

When using powershell to rename files with their directory name and file name, my code works, **except** in the first file in a directory, it gives it two copies of the directory name. So the file `book1.xlsx` in folder `folder1` should become `folder1book1.xlsx` but it becomes `folder1folder1book1.xlsx`. The remaining files in `folder1` are correctly named `folder1book2.xlsx`, `folder1book3.xlsx`, etc.

I have a directory, with many sub-directories. In each sub-dir are files that need their sub-dir name added in.

I've been following this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20874916). For me it looks like:

```
dir -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Directory.Name + "_" + $_.Name}
```

I've also tried

--setting the `Recurse -Depth 1` so that it doesn't keep looking for folders in the sub-folders.

--using `ForEach-Object {$_ | ...` after the pipe, similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25271104).

--running it in Visual Studio Code rather than directly in PowerShell, which turns it into:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\my\dir\here" -Filter *.xls -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.DirectoryName + '_' + $_.Name}
```

--putting an empty folder inside the sub-directory, setting `-Depth 2` to see if that will "catch" the recurse loop

I would expect the files to be named `folder1_book1.xlsx`, `folder1_book2.xlsx`, `folder1_book3.xlsx`.

**But all of the attempted changes above give the same result.** The first file is named `folder1_folder1_book1.xlsx` [INCORRECT], `folder1_book2.xlsx`[CORRECT], `folder1_book3.xlsx`[CORRECT].

A workaround might be writing an `if` statement for "not files that contain the sub-directory name" [as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32333890/powershell-file-rename). But the link searches for a text string not an object (probably not the correct term) like `@_.Directory.Name`. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113467/5373210) shows how to concatenate objects but not something like `@_.Directory.Name`. Having to put in an if statement seems like an unnecessary step if `-Recurse` worked the way it should, so I'm not sure this workaround gets at the heart of the issue.

I'm running windows 10 with bootcamp on a 2018 iMac (I'm in Windows a lot because I use ArcMap). Powershell 5.1.17134.858. Visual Studio Code 1.38.0. This is a task I would like to learn how to use more in the future, so explanations will help. I'm new to using PowerShell. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you see the behavior if you instead collect the files up front and then iterate with `foreach`?

Comment: as `Bill_Stewart` implied, that behavior is a side effect of how PoSh is loading the file list when you feed GCI directly into a pipeline. the fix is either [1] use a `foreach` **_loop_** instead of a `ForEach-Object` pipeline stage OR get the whole collection up front and then feed it to the pipeline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell, rename-item doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42470793/powershell-rename-item-doesnt-work-as-expected) (pay attention to the note in the end of **mklements0**'s answer, thus: `(dir -Filter *.xlsx -Recurse) | Rename-Item...`)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, what would a foreach loop look like in code?

Comment: @iRon thank you for clarifying what "up front" meant and pointing to the very end of that post. The () did the trick. I also found that instead adding `Sort-Object -Property Name |` as the second line works as well. Is this a solution or just a duplicate?

Comment: @BonnieM - you seem to have found one fix = wrapping the 1st stage of the pipeline in `()` to force it to fully evaluate before sending things to the next stage. ///// the `foreach` loop runs things in a LOOP instead of one-at-a-time thru the pipeline. so it would be something like `foreach ($Thing in $Collection) {Do-Stuff -To $Thing}`

Comment: It works for me.  Can you give a reproducible example that doesn't work (win10 ps 5.1)?

Comment: Oh, I see it now without the -whatif.  It's still reading the subdirectory after the rename.  Parentheses around the first pipeline element makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This was a script I created for one of my customers that may help

<##################################################################################################################################

This script can be used to search through folders to rename files from their 
original name to "filename_foldername.extension". To use this script 
please configure the items listed below.

Items to Congfigure
-$Original
-$Source
-$Destination
-$Files

Also please change the Out-File date on line 29 to today's date ****Example: 2019-10-02****

We've also added a change log file that is named "FileChange.txt" and can be found in the location identified on line 30

## >

```
$Original="C:\temp\test" #Location of ".cab" files copied
$Source="C:\temp\Test" #Location were ".cab" files are stored
$Destination="C:\temp\Test\2019-10-02" #Location were you want to copy ".cab" files after the file name change. Be sure to change the date to the date you run this script. The script creates a folder with todays date
$Files=@("*.cab") #Choose the file type you want to search for
$ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue" #Suppress Errors

Get-ChildItem $Original -Include "*.cab" -File -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.BaseName+"_"+$_.Directory.Name +'.cab'}
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ".\$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd'))"; Get-ChildItem -recurse ($Source) -include ($Files) | Copy-Item -Destination ($Destination) -EA SilentlyContinue
Get-ChildItem $Original | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -ge [datetime]::Now.AddMinutes(-10)} | Out-File C:\temp\test\2019-10-02\FileChange.txt
```